# Where would I put external API call code in my rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project that has two models Author and Book. They have a many to many relationship. I am planning to create two controllers Authors and Books.

Now lets say I have an external API making the call ex: '/authors/{#author_id}' I want to return the author along with all book information for that particular author. Where would I place this external API code? In the case of the above example would I just place the code along with the Authors controller that is used by my app or do I place the external API code else where to distinguish between external API code and code used internally by my app?

Comment: In a seperate class. You can call this class a service object or a client object but whatever you do don't do API calls in your models or controllers (they already have responsibilites).  If you want inspiration looking at [existing API clients for popular APIs](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients). Beyond that its really an off-topic question as its purely opinion based.

Comment: @max What do you mean by "they already have responsibilities". What responsibility does a controller have that distinguishes itself from a Service object or a client Object? What is the responsibility of a typical Service object or Client object?

Comment: A controller has a huge number of responsibilities - it has to respond to HTTP requests, and pass the user input to models and then pass the models to the view as well as additional stuff like authorization. A service object only has one responsibility - which is whatever you designate it's job to be. That's kind of the point of that design pattern.

Comment: A client object on the other hand often has more public  methods (SOs often have only one) and serves more as a middle hand between your app and the external API.

Comment: @max Ok. Also, going back to your original comment you said that I could draw inspiration from https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients I am sort of new to all of this. Can you point to one API that I could possibly emulate?

Comment: [bitly](https://github.com/philnash/bitly) is a relatively simple one.

Comment: @max Ok. Right now I have only one api call but in the future I might have more. So do I create a new Service object for each API call? Doesn't that make things too cluttered?

Comment: It depends. I would use a combination of a client and service objects. The client talks to the API and the service object ties together the interaction between the API and your models. The services would be for example `ImportUserService` which uses `FooAPI::Client.find_users`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create service for that, here is a more info aboiut this pattern: https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/06/17/using-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails.html and https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial